# Loading JavaScript Scripts in Order

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am loading a few scripts using JavaScript $ajax in an async manner.  I need them to load in a certain order but at the moment it's random.

The code I have is:

```
loadScripts();

function loadScripts() {
    getBootStrapperScript(function (callback) {            
      alert('bootStrapper loaded');
    })

    getXMLScript(function (callback) {       
        alert('xml script loaded');
    });

    getFormScript(function (callback) {       
        alert('form script loaded');
    });       
}

function getBootStrapperScript(callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/eSales/scripts/bootStrapper.js",
        dataType: "script"
    }).done(callback); 
}

function getXMLScript(callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/eSales/scripts/LoadXML.js",
        dataType: "script"
    }).done(callback);
}

function getFormScript(callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/eSales/scripts/LoadForm.js",
        dataType: "script"  
    }).done(callback);
}
```

You can see it running in this [jsFIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DFWrw/)

Is there a nice and elegant way of ensuring the scripts load in the order they are defined?

Comment: yeah, I've been looking at that my end-game solution :) - thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$.getScript()` returns a jQuery deferred object so you can use it like so

```
$.getScript("firstScript").done( function( ) {
    $.getScript("secondScript").done( function( ) {
        $.getScript("thirdScript").done( function( ) {
            alert("scripts loaded");
        });
    });
});
```

Fiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/DFWrw/4/)

Answer (score 8):

```
function loadScripts(urls, callback) {
    var i = 0;
    (function loadNextScript() {
         if (i < urls.length) {
              $.getScript(urls[i][0]).done(function() {
                  alert(urls[i][1] + " loaded");  // probably remove in production
                  ++i;
                  loadNextScript();
              });
         }
         else if (callback) callback();
    })();
}

loadScripts([
    ["http://localhost/eSales/scripts/bootStrapper.js", "bootstrapper script"],
    ["http://localhost/eSales/scripts/LoadXML.js", "xml script"],
    ["http://localhost/eSales/scripts/LoadForm.js", "form script"]
], function() { alert('done'); });
```

Comment: Cleanest solution in IMHO. You can even have a per-script callback.

Answer (score 2):

Predefine your functions and then execute them one after another by passing them as callbacks. This works because it requires each to load before passing to the next one and as such response times won't be an issue any longer for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can call the next ajax function in the callback of the other

```
getBootStrapperScript(function (callback) {            
    alert('bootStrapper loaded');
    getFormScript(function (callback) {       
        alert('form script loaded');
    });
})
```

Comment: I don't think this is elegant. As you add new files to load, the code becomes harder to read.

Comment: This is more of an example how to do this. Of course you can always wrap the `getFormScript` call (and the others) into it's own function and call them instead. But the technique how to achieve sequential loading doesn't change.

Comment: Yes, but still, the request was a 'nice and elegant' way. This is just my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You could be loading them inside the callbacks to ensure a certain order. Although this looks messy

```
function loadScripts() {
  getBootStrapperScript(function (callback) {            
    alert('bootStrapper loaded');
    getXMLScript(function (callback) {       
       alert('xml script loaded');
       getFormScript(function (callback) {       
         alert('form script loaded');
       });       
    }); 
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to assign each call to a variable as it completes, and then do something like this:

```
var script1, script2, script3;

var init = function() {

    if (script1 && script2 && script3)
    {
        // now inject scripts in order
    }

};

function getBootStrapperScript(callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost/eSales/scripts/bootStrapper.js",
        dataType: "script"
    }).done(function(data) { 
        script1 = data; 
        init(); 
    }); 
}

// Do your other two calls in similar fashion
```

What will happen is that the init() will only execute the if statement when all the script variables have been assigned and then you can choose the order they get inserted into the page.

EDIT: It is wrong to chain your calls together like the other answers are suggesting as this will reduce readability and performance.

EDIT2: The requirement is only that the scripts load into memory sequentially... not that they are brought down from the server sequentially.

Comment: His requirements asks for the scripts to be loaded sequentially. This is especially true if there are dependencies within the other scripts.

Comment: My answer does not preclude that, unless I have missed something?

Comment: Ahhh ok... what I was trying to say was the if you chain the ajax calls one after another in their respective callback functions you not only make it less readable for developers, it also means that they get pulled down sequentially and use more stack.

I think his requirement was just that they get loaded into memory sequentially rather than order of transfer.